# Why is the view set to fullscreen in a dialog with custom style set 

Tags: java, android-layout

I have a `style.xml`

```
<resources>
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/stonebook</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

I want customize my dialog with this style:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(SimpleTestActivity.this,R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
dialog.show();
```

Why is the dialog set to fullscreen not the size of the drawable?

Event i add the code with:

```
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
```

It didn't change, still stretches to the fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `android:windowIsFloating` in `style.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/stonebook</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```